# how disable radio button according to selected choice?

Tags: android

I have two radio buttons on a form, I want to be able to disable one of the textboxes when the option box is selected. Pls help, I am very new to android. Thank you for you time. Here is my code

```
rgRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);

OnCheckedChangeListener listener=new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

         switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.radio0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Male", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            r0.setEnabled(false);
            break;

        case R.id.radio1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FeMale", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            r1.setEnabled(false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using it:

```
  setEnabled(false);
```